# WebLogic 12cR2 Partition Administrator can't connect to server

Tags: encryption, weblogic, administrator, partition

Since FMW 12.2.1.0.0, Weblogic start support partition administrator to manage their own partition was created in same domain.

I had followed online guideline:
    https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/create_weblogic_server_domain_with

to create realm, user/group, virtual target, partition, and partition IDD. I start the multiple partition properly.

But, I had encountered a very annoy issue. Weblogic server never get partition administrator connect through.

When I created user by WLST as (by given 'userName', 'realmName' and 'userPassword'):

```
atn = realm.lookupAuthenticationProvider('ATNPartition')
if atn.userExists(userName):
  print "User already exists."
else:
  atn.createUser(userName, '${userPassword}', realmName + ' Realm User')
  print "Done creating user. ${userPassword}"
```

after save and activated, suppose Weblogic server will save the user password in encrypted format in config.sh. But unfortunately, when I check the config.sh in domain home. There is only node manger's password was encrypted as:

```
<credential-encrypted>{AES}BO8/YDwxxF0YEtwOysWoxIaNk589vHRypbPqtuKfDcTufqi9jne15LfyDfKHwKJuaz0hjkALY1qzInAlhVLmeCZk3pTjV+5+260PhCNKzlE15j2YafCPONhYwtfYryFx</credential-encrypted>
<node-manager-username>weblogic</node-manager-username>
<node-manager-password-encrypted>{AES}ZhuXoR4rh4aIv2zNCyugU0X+9BUb6oBaEYS6qBgQ688=</node-manager-password-encrypted>
```

I don't see any other partition administrator's password encryption information.

Please any one advise me How to enable Weblogic server to support partition administrator connect to Weblogic server?

Answer (score 0):

This is self reply as I found the answer by my self.

As FMW 12.2.1 deployed the partition level, the deployment context as:

```
/Partitions/${partition}/ResourceGroups/${resource_group}/AppDeployments>
```

Application can be accessed by:

```
deployedApp = getMBean('/Partitions/'+${partition}+'/ResourceGroups/'+${resource_group}+'/AppDeployments/'+appName>)
```

This may help some one in same situation.